# Trigger event on main ViewController when app becomes active after receiving push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I've successfully implemented push notification for my app. 
What I'm trying to accomplish now is sending some sort of flag to the root `ViewController` from my `AppDelegate`, in case the app received PN.

I started by checking for badge number in my `applicationDidBecomeActive:`, like so:

```
if (application.applicationIconBadgeNumber>0) {
        self.hasNotification = YES;
        NSLog(@"APNs Message received");            
    }
```

Now, I'm not sure how to convey this message to my root `ViewController` in order to trigger a segue that will take the user to one of the views. What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that many view controllers might be interested in this event, this sounds like a good candidate to use the publish/subscribe model provided by NSNotifications.

**To publish a notification:**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyEventName" object:optionalPayload];
```

**To Subscribe to a Notification:**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:)
        name:@"MyEventName" object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
   //Unsubscribe yourself in dealloc
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

-(void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)pNotification
{
    NSLog(@"#1 received message = %@",(NSString*)[pNotification object]);    
    //Perform your segue here
}
```

**Alternative: Custom Root VC**

If you've created your own *domain-specific* container view controller as the root view controller, you could do the following:

- Send the event to the root view controller.
- The root view controller will ask its current child/children if they're interested in the event (perhaps via a marker protocol), and propagate it.

I almost always use a custom container - RootViewController - in my applications, as it can lead to nicely readable code that describes exactly what is happening. Not only that, but it also makes it very simple to implement the core layout stuff (eg sliding menus, etc) from here.